# Pull string which is surrounded by "/" from a string C#

Tags: c#, regex, string

I would like to take the **words** of a sentence, if that word has in each end, the forward slash character `/`

For example, a string should contain spaces so may have to pull a string from something like:

*Example:*

```
"Hello /World/" --> "World"
```

Would I have to use regular expressions for this, if so, could you tell me how to do this please? If not, how could I do it in a really basic way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Regex,

```
string[] results = Regex.Matches("Hello /World/ hello /universe/",@"/(.+?)/")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m=>m.Groups[1].Value)
    .ToArray();
```

would return `World` and `universe`

Comment: @user1290653 and from "Hello /World hello universe/" it would return `World hello universe` does this still meet your definition of a "word"? I think it would be probably better to use `@"/(\p{L}+)/"` or if the word can contain other characters than letters try `@"/([\p{L}-]+)/"` and add all additional character in the character class, like I added the dash.

Answer (score 2):

Loop through all the characters. Get the first index of / on the position find the paired last / on the position and remove anything between by creating a new string. Keep looping and find the opening and closing / until finish.

Get the first index of /, last index of / and split and string.substring() it.

Comment: i like that, ill try that now :)